# Rendering html in Gecko browser

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, gecko

I have Gecko browser in a form and need to specify the HTML to render as opposed to the Url to navigate to.  How do I do this?

```
public Form1()
{
        var xulPath = @"C:\Users\Jeff\Downloads\XulRunner";

        Skybound.Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(xulPath);
        InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var body = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
              <html><body>Hello World!</body></html>";
        geckoWebBrowser1. ___________????______ = body;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using the [GeckoFX-29.0](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0) project, the official method to load html into the browser seems to be `LoadHtml(string htmlDocument`).

For example:
`geckoWebBrowser1.LoadHtml("<html><body><h1>Hello!!!</h1></body></html>");`

See https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/src/eead77c1a7e2e8a483e5ca97fdcaa5291af8ad21/Geckofx-Winforms/GeckoWebBrowser.cs?at=default for reference.

Comment: The LoadHtml(string content, string url) overload is actually better to call than LoadHtml(string content) (which should prolly be deprecated) as it loads the page a better way.

Comment: I guess you would leave the `string url` to be `null`? What is the purpose of both providing a `content` and a `url` argument? Wouldn't it be easier to provide 2 different methods?

Comment: the url isn't actually loaded. Rather its the url that firefox thinks is loaded.